# 3-phase, 220 V motor wiring

Tags: motor, wiring

I have a pump motor that I was trying to wire. It's been a long time since I've wired a motor and I haven't seen one with just 4 wire connections- U, V, W, and ground. I have 220 V, 3-phase power.

Can I wire it directly to a plug that can be plugged in to turn on and run the motor? Or do I have to have a controller?

Also, do my red and black wires go to the U and V terminal and  the neutral wire to the W terminal? That other terminal is the ground.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What country you live? Are you sure you have 3x220V/60Hz or you are wrong and you have 3x400V/50Hz.  You should have 5 wires: 3 phases, neutral, ground. Forget the neutral for this case. Measure the phase to phase voltage.

Answer (score 1):

U, V, and W are all power. Ground is obviously, ground. Uggh, I can't read Chinese. :)

In three-phase 220v AC, the UVW colors are all but meaningless. They may be black/red/white, or yellow/orange/red... really anything. But a "neutral" should never be used in 3-phase wiring.

You can wire them in any order. If the pump runs in reverse (hope that doesn't destroy it...) just switch any of the two leads - like U and V. Then it will run in the other direction.

Any 3-phase motor should be fused, and the vast majority use a contactor (glorified relay) to start/stop. The proper way to wire this would be 
SOURCE --> FUSES --> CONTACTOR --> PUMP.  Then it's "always on", and simply activating the contactor (which can be done from 220 or even 110) starts and stops the pump.

Comment: "*But a "neutral" should never be used in 3-phase wiring.*" You should qualify this. Obviously it is used in for certain applications but generally not in three-phase motors.

Answer (score 1):

The wiring here is 3-phase "delta", meaning 220V between any two phase wires.  Note the symbol above the 60Hz mark.   You can supply it with either 220V "delta" or 220V "wye", in both cases phase-to-phase power must be 220V.

In the case of "wye" or "wild-leg delta" you will not be using the neutral.  *Keep in mind that in most of the world, the power is "wye", 220V phase-to-neutral/ground and 384-400V phase-phase.  That is the wrong power for this*.

"W" has nothing to do with "white".   That is unrelated.

Assuming you are in the North American sphere of influence for wiring (Japan, parts of Philippines, American possessions), **white means neutral**.  You would not be using neutral.

Now, if you are using multi-wire flexible cable, the stock colors are black white red and ground.   This type of cable will work fine for 220V "delta" wiring, but make sure it is actually connected to real 3-phase with a triple breaker or triple fuses.  *If it is fed by a double breaker, that is 120/240V split-phase, white is neutral, and it cannot power this motor.*

In this case you would be using white for a *hot phase*, so you need to wrap several loops of black or color tape around the wire to mark it as *not a neutral*.  Do this on both ends of the wire if possible.   Black tape is fine, it doesn't matter what colors the 3 wires are, as long as they are not white, gray or green.

You hook the three hot wires to the three U,V,W terminals.  It doesn't matter which is which **however you have a 50/50 chance of the motor spinning the wrong direction**.  You need to be on guard the first time you start it up to check for correct rotation, and shut it off immediately if wrong.  The motor will be happy spinning either direction, *but the pump may not*.   (This can really getcha with air compressors, they seem to work but the *oil* pump is running backwards. Rebuild time!)

If it does spin the wrong way, swap any two of the hot wires.

Comment: One of the best explanations I saw for Non-American understand your system! I have a question: US homes do have the 3-phase 120° system 220V phase to phase? Or they are just 120V+120V made by 180° 1-phase transformer winding? And if something I said is wrong, please realign me - or send a link with correct information. Thanks In advance.

Comment: @EJE we have both.  Most places it is 120+120V with a 1-phase 240V transformer center tap.  In very urban developments it's 3-phase "wye" (120V leg-neutral and 208V leg-leg), that motor would be happy there.  Brazil does that, but 127V leg-neutral and 220V leg-leg, thus allowing it to use everyone's appliances lol.  USA is only stuck with 120V because early receptacles were for lights, and then things snowballed LOL. We do have 240V receptacle types available...

Comment: You nailed it:I do live in Brazil and  either 127V and 220V powered cities use the same lamp receptacle (E27) in 99.9% of cases. At least for incandescent, CFL and LED ones, either voltage - this in Rio city. Something that you may not know is that our cities that say 220V this is indeed for Phase-Neutral voltage (any shock is nastier, as in Europe), and Phase-Phase is then 380V. Frequency is alway 60Hz.  I lived for 2 years in Austin - TX and had the perception most homes just used this 120+120 V that being bi-phased (180 degrees apart), could not really generate a rotating field.